# Multiple viewmodels sharing a service with notification

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

Question: I have two viewmodels that share a service with a list. My question is how to setup the notification so that both viewmodels know when this list is changed. Description below and code of where i'm at.

I found this example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963428/684042) that looks right for what I'm trying to do, but I have a question regarding how to be notified in my viewmodels of a change in my service. I'll add some code I've mocked up to see if I'm on the right track. I'm using WPF/MVVM Light.

First part is a service with a interface that will have a list of data, in this example I'm using a string list. I want a property in both viewmodels to have access to this list of data, and be notified when it's changed. I think what's throwing me is the interface IOC into my viewmodels. I'm understanding more and more why this is good, but I'm still wrapping my mind around it and I'm not sure how to setup the notification when the list is changed in the service. If my service was not injected I might have setup a event or property that my viewmodel property would access get/set but injecting my service does not expose my public fields, just methods. This is new to me so it's very likely i'm not understanding this correctly or missing something.

I used a List in my service instead of a ObservableCollection based on some reading I've done warning against using the ObservableCollection here.  Thanks you for any help.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> getMyList()
    {
        return this.myList;
    }
    public void setMyList(List<string> value)
    {
        this.myList = value;
    }
    public void addValue(string value)
    {
        this.myList.Add(value);
    }
    public void insertValue(int index, string value)
    {
        this.myList.Insert(index, value);
    }
}

public class MyViewModelOne : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyViewModelOne(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public List<string> MyProperty // control item source will bind to this
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myService.getSource();
        }
    }
    public void setSomeValue(value)
    {
        this.myService.addValue(value);
    }
}

public class MyViewModelTwo : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyViewModelTwo(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public List<string> MyProperty // control item source will bind to this
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myService.getSource();
        }
    }
    public void setSomeValue(value)
    {
        this.myService.addValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to handle the notification. Say viewmodelone changes the list in the service, how will viewmodeltwo know about it? Shared data but uses different in each viewmodel. - Try reword above to make the question more clear.

Comment: Doesn't MVVM Light provide a messaging system ?

Comment: I would recommend either adding a `ListChanged` event to your `MyService` class that your ViewModels can subscribe to, or look into MVVM Light's `Messenger` class to have `MyService` broadcast a "This list has changed" message anytime a change occurs, and your ViewModels can subscribe to receive those kinds of messages and run `OnPropertyChanged(MyProperty)` to refresh the UI.

Comment: I think i'm missing something. I tried to create a event in my service but I can't access fields from the service injected into my viewmodels, so i'm not sure how to implement it, but i'm very likely missing something obvious. I'm open for handling this any way, if my approach is not wise i'm open for any ideas. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: @Terco Your `MyService` would make a public event of something like `ListChanged`, and raise that event anytime the list changed. Your ViewModels would subscribe to `myService.ListChanged += HandleMyService_ListChanged` and whenever that event occured, it would run something like `RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty")` to alert anything bound to `MyProperty` that it needed to update and re-run the `get` method.

Comment: I thought that would work too, when I put a event in MyService and goto to my viewmodel i type myService. but I only see my methods resolved, I don't see any fields or events/delegates, and they are public. Was not sure if that's how it worked because of how i passed in the dataservice interface to my viewmodel or if I was missing something.

Comment: @Terco Make sure you add the event to `IMyService` too since that is the datatype your ViewModels are working with. Also, if you type my name with a @ symbol in front of it the way I do with yours, it will give me a notification when you reply to me and I'll probably respond faster :)

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I could not get it working so I just implemented the mvvmlight messenger which is working. I still prefer to do this with a service though, I'm going to go try again and see what I'm missing in the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working two different ways, I went with the first example because I think it's easier to follow in the code.

This came up because I had a control in my mainview with related code that was growing and I realized I wanted the same control/behavior in a separate view that would use the same data/control for a different purpose. 
I did not want to duplicate this control/template/code in two places so I made it into a User Control. I then nest the user control in my views. The user control has it's own VM. The main view updates the service with new data, and the nested control listens on a event to know when there is new data.

Still very new to MVVM thinking so please feel free to point out in issues with either of these examples.

**Example using a service with eventhandler.**

```
public interface IMyInterface
{   
    event EventHandler OnSomeEvent;
    void addSomeData(string value);
    void getSomeData();
}

public class MyInterface: IMyInterface
{
    public event EventHandler OnSomeEvent = delegate { };  

    public void addSomeData(string value)
    {
        // do stuff
        OnSomeEvent();
    }
    public string getSomeData()
    {
        return "some data";
    }
}

// Main ViewModel
public class ViewModelOne : ViewModelBase
{
    IMyInterface myInterface;
    public NotifyViewModel(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
        this.myInterface.OnItemSourceChanged += myInterface_OnSomeEvent;
    }

    void testEvent()
    {
        this.myInterface.addSomeData("test data");
    }
}

// My nested user control
public class ViewModelTwo : ViewModelBase
{
    IMyInterface myInterface;
    public NotifyViewModel(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
        this.myInterface.OnItemSourceChanged += myInterface_OnSomeEvent;
    }

    void myInterface_OnSomeEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**Example using MVVM Light Messaging**

```
public class EventDataSource
{
    public string MyItemSource { get; set; }
    public EventDataSource()
    {
        MyItemSource = string.Empty;
    }

}

// Message class
public class MyDataSourceMessage : MessageBase
{
    public EventDataSource MyItemSource { get; set; }
    public MyDataSourceMessage(EventDataSource myItemSource)
    {
        MyItemSource = myItemSource;
    }
}

// Main ViewModel
public class ViewModelOne : ViewModelBase
{
    public NotifyViewModel() {}

    void testMessage()
    {
        EventDataSource msg = new EventDataSource() { MyItemSource = "magic message!"};
        Messenger.Default.Send(new MyDataSourceMessage(msg as EventDataSource));
    }
}

// My nested user control
public class ViewModelTwo : ViewModelBase
{

    public NotifyViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<MyDataSourceMessage>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> myProperty = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty: = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProperty);
        }
    }
    void ReceiveMessage(MyDataSourceMessage action)
    {
        // do something with the data
        MyProperty.Add(action.DGItemSource.ItemSource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood about your problem, what you need essentially is that your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation at your service level and the list my list to be an ObservableCollection being injected from the service.

Now if there is a notification change it would be directly on the service and hence no explicit need of handling.

Your binding could look like `"{Binding MyService.MyProperty}"`

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me try to shed some light on this. First of all, change notification is not meant to pass information between view models, it is meant to notify the view itself that the a property of the view model has changed.

There are a few methods for view models to issue change notifications to views:

1. [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface
2. [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface
3. A custom event with the name of the property suffixed with `Changed` (e.g. an event called `MyPropChanged` for a property called `MyProp`)

Having said all that, it is still possible for one view model to subscribe to the events generated by the above methods, and if you really need to, you may of course.

**EDIT:**

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794276.aspx#id0070065) for a description on item number 3 above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through these options. I'm looking for a good way to handle this, I don't have to work it like my original question poses.